# How to make Post request with Axios (MERN Stack)

Tags: axios, mern

I am new to REACT and the MERN Stack and try to understand everything. But sometimes, it seems that the simplest things do not want to get into my head.
I hope that, one day, I will understand it all. Until then it still seems a long way away. Anyway. I am starting with a simple MERN app. All users should be displayed on the start page. On a separate "page" there should be a create users form. For now, the users are displayed on the home screen but when I switch back from the "create users page" they dissappeared. Furthermore the input form do not work (validation error). When checking get and posts requests from my backend with Thunder Client everthing works, so I suppose, this might be something to do with the frontend. Sorry for my wording. I am a programming newbie.
I hope it is somewhat understandable. What am I doing wrong? I would be so happy, if anyone could help. Thank you!

client/src/App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import AllUsers from "./pages/AllUsers";
import Navigation from "./components/Navigation";
import CreateUser from "./pages/CreateUser";

import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navigation />

      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<AllUsers />} />
        <Route path="create-User" element={<CreateUser />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

client/src/components/Navigation.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <header className="bg-background border-t-0 shadow-none">
      <nav className="bg-navigation bg-opacity-40 rounded-t-xs flex justify-around h-12 p-3 ">
        <Link to="/create-user">Create User</Link>
        <Link to="/">
          <img id="workshop-icon" src="../assets/home.svg" alt="home button" />
        </Link>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```

client/src/AllUsers.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";

const AllUsers = () => {
  const [listOfUsers, setListOfUsers] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/getUsers").then((response) => {
      setListOfUsers(response.data);
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="usersDisplay">
        {listOfUsers.map((user) => {
          return (
            <div key={user._id}>
              <h1>Name: {user.name}</h1>
              <h1>Age: {user.age}</h1>
              <h1>Username: {user.username}</h1>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AllUsers;
```

client/src/createUser.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";

const CreateUser = () => {
  const [listOfUsers, setListOfUsers] = useState([]);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [age, setAge] = useState(0);
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");

  Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/createUser", {
    name,
    age,
    username,
  }).then((response) => {
    setListOfUsers([
      ...listOfUsers,
      {
        name,
        age,
        username,
      },
    ]);
  });

  return (
    <div className="input">
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Name..."
          onChange={(event) => {
            setName(event.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <input
          type="number"
          placeholder="Age..."
          onChange={(event) => {
            setAge(event.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Username..."
          onChange={(event) => {
            setUsername(event.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <button onClick={CreateUser}> Create User </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CreateUser;
```

Comment: Are you sure your `AllUsers` component is even rendering when you navigate back to `/`? I suspect you need to mark your root route as `exact`

Comment: This: `onClick={CreateUser}` doesn't look right (together with sending a POST request with every render of the `CreateUser` component). You should create a separate function that sends that POST request, and call this function when the **Create User** button is clicked.